# Customizing Checkout page labels

Tags: square-connect

I am using Square Checkout as documented [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/square-checkout-getstarted), and the end to end flow is working fine.

Is there a way to customize the labels/text on the Checkout and the confirmation pages? For example can we change "Shipping information" to "Billing information", and "Shipping address" to "Billing address" ?

Comment: Please add some code instead of a _here_ link.

Comment: Hi @Clijsters this is not about code, as mentioned the entire workflow of Checkout using Square is working fine. I Just need to check if we can change the labels/text of the Square's Checkout page. [screenshot](http://imgur.com/810DmHF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that at this time. See all the options here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-createcheckout

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation @tristansokol